# How can we disable a custom post type archive page but enable its feed?

Tags: custom-post-types, feed

To disable a custom post types archive page, we should use the following code:

```
$args = array(
    'has_archive' => false,
);
```

But when we use `false` for `has_archive`, the feeds page (like : `name.com/books/feed`) of that custom post type becomes disabled too. Now I want to know how I can disable custom post types archive page but keep the feed active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution for it. I set `has_archive` to `true`. Now both the feed and the archive page of CPT are active. To only disable the archive page of CPT, I use the following filter in the `functions.php` file:

```
function AryanThemes_disable_cpt_archive_template(){
    if ( is_post_type_archive('cpt') ) {
        global $wp_query;
      $wp_query->set_404();
      status_header( 404 );
      get_template_part( 404 ); exit();
  }
}
add_filter( 'archive_template', 'AryanThemes_disable_cpt_archive_template', -1 );
```

Answer (score 5):

Set the `feeds` argument of `rewrite` to `true` to generate feed rewrite rules. It defaults to whatever `has_archive` is set to if nothing is explicitly passed.

```
$args = array(
    'has_archive' => false,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'feeds' => true
    ),
    // your other args...
);
```

Comment: I use this method also but feed not generate.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Be sure to flush rewrite rules after implementing this.